# How can i collect all items of an array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array which is :

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String a1 = edittext.getText().toString();
int integer = Integer.parseInt(a1);
array.add(integer);
```

like that. There are about 15 items but I don't know exactly how much they are.
I want to collect all items on this array. How can I do that ? While or something else?

I hope you will able to understand my problem. I don't know English very well.

Comment: Does `edittext` contains the 15 items?

Comment: The person put a value and save that then do that again how much do you want. like that edittext 80 saved same edittext 30 etc.

Comment: @TayfunKarakaş array != `ArrayList`

Comment: Are you adding these values in Android app, when button is clicked?

Comment: What is `edittext` ?

Comment: yes arraylist have about 15 integer but i cant loop those integers.

Comment: Look at my answer. Just use a `for-each` to iterate through your `ArrayList`

Comment: I really do not understand what your issue is here, you may simply loop your array like I showed you. That will go through *every* item in your list. Do you want an extended answer?

Comment: I just looked your answer but i dont know how can i do that :(

Comment: No worries. Give me a few minutes I'll try to explain it easier in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much I will be here.

Comment: @TayfunKarakaş - I have tried simplifying it for you. Take a look.

Comment: I fixed my problem thanks a lot to everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to collect all items on this array. How can i do that ? while or something else?

Iterate through every element in the `Array` using a `for-each`:

```
for(Integer i : array){
  //Do whatever you want to do
}
```

That loop is either called a `for-each` or `advanced for-loop`. It will iterate through every `Object` in your array and returns that object *(In your case, `Integer i`)*

OR

Use a regular for-loop. You probably used it before so it will be easier for you -

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
 Integer item = array.get(i);
}
```

---

To implicitly tackle your code, I will be assuming:

1. You're receiving user input
2. You wish to parse user input to an Integer (Meaning you only want numbers)
3. You want to repeat this loop *X* number of times.

If there's something I'm missing please correct me.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Integer tempInteger;
    try{
        tempInteger = Integer.parseInt(edittext.getText().toString());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    array.add(tempInteger);

    /*
     * Once you have your array filled with 'elements' (In your case
     * with Integer values) you can use the following loop called a 
     * 'for-each' loop to loop through ALL the elements in your list.
     */
    for(Integer i : array){
        System.out.println("array["+array.get(i)+"]" + " = " + i);
    }
```

OR

Using a regular `for-loop`:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++){
        Integer myInteger = array.get(i);
        System.out.println("array["+i+"]" + " = " + myInteger);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand the question correct.
To get each item in array you may do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
     Integer item = array.get(i);
     //do whatever you want with item
}
```

Here is how to find a sum of all items in array:

```
Integer sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
     sum += array.get(i);
}
//sum is now contains sum of all items
```

Comment: i know that but i can't loop that all i on array list

Comment: Sorry, but i don't really understand what do you want to do with this array. Just iterate, find sum of elements, or smth else.

Comment: I just want to loop items on array list. Such as array.get(i) + array.get(i+1) but I couldt make it worked.

Comment: Tayfun Karakaş, Ok, just updated answer, there is how to find a summ of all elements in an array